# How can i use PHP-SteamCommunity without composer

Tags: php, steam

Im trying to figure out how to use this lib without composer
Because i couldnt not install it correctly on my pc

Link to lib on GitHub: https://github.com/waylaidwanderer/PHP-SteamCommunity.

Comment: Why don't you ask on GitHub? There are more chances to get an answer.

And why do you even ask? Do you have any error with the lib or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer listed depencencies on the following page:
https://libraries.io/github/waylaidwanderer/PHP-SteamCommunity

**composer.json**

- phpseclib/phpseclib
- phpunit/phpunit

**composer.lock**

- phpseclib/phpseclib
- phpunit/php-code-coverage
- phpunit/php-file-iterator
- phpunit/php-text-template
- phpunit/php-timer
- phpunit/php-token-steam
- phpunit/phpunit
- phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects
- symfony/yaml